# Just trying to give a bold font to an input text but every it show normal text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give a bold font to an input this way below but it doesn't work show as a plan text simple

```
<input style="font-weight: bold;" name="lg" id="ur" type="hidden" required="" value="<? echo ?>" > <? echo ;?>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Do you really see the input? Hidden inputs are never visible in a webpage.

Comment: i just want to hide my box that can user can enter echo text but in box that ..<input class=""hidden" style="font-weight: bold;" name="lo" id="ur" type="text" required="" value="<? echo ?>" > i use this but no effective

Answer (score 3):

You have `type="hidden"`, so the input won't be shown.

I'm guessing that you added the inline style to the wrong input.

If not, then you should change the type to `type="text"`.

Good luck.

Comment: actually i want to hide my box just show plan text by echo request

Comment: <input class=""hidden" style="font-weight: bold;" name="lo" id="ur" type="text" required="" value="<? echo ?>" >

Comment: I don't get what you mean, then why use an input if you only want to echo a string>??? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change code to

```
<input style="font-weight: bold;" name="lg" id="ur" type="text" required="" value="<? echo ?>" > <? echo ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the explanation given by the OP in the comments, I guess the OP just wanna print a text from a PHP variable or plain text.

For this you don't need `<input>`. You can simply use a HTML tag and add the style attribute to it. And the simplest solution is,

```
<strong><?php echo "Something"; ?></strong>
```